Can't find page access token and permissions
My project is to post on Facebook using open ai generated content and I created a developers account along with a new Facebook account I need page access token and permissions but the only permissions allowed to me are email, public and payment permissions and I can't get access to page access token and I don't know how to set api endpoint here for redirect url.
I tried making the model that generates the caption but I can't put it here it shows error of not having the valid token
